# Counter-examples to $\text{im}(T_1) + \text{im}(T_2) \subseteq \text{im}(T_1 + T_2) $ and $\ker(T_1 + T_2) \subseteq\ker(T_1) \cap \ker(T_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear transformations from $U$ to $V$.

The counter-examples that I found to 
$$ \text{im}(T_1) + \text{im}(T_2) \subseteq \text{im}(T_1 + T_2) \tag{1}$$ 
is : 
Suppose $B=\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a basis for $R^2$. $T_1: R^2\to R^2$ is defined by $T_1(av_1+bv_2)=a$; $T_2: R^2->R^2$ is defined by $T_2(av_1+bv_2)=-a$. Then $im(T_1)=R $, $im(T_2)=R$ but $im(T_1 + T_2)=\{0\}$.

The counter-examples that I found to 
$$\ker(T_1 + T_2) \subseteq \text{ker}(T_1) \cap \text{ker}(T_2)\tag 2$$ 
is : 
Let $A=$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}, $B=$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$T_1: R^2\to R^2$ is defined by $T_1(v)=Av$; $T_2: R^2->R^2$ is defined by $T_2(v)=Bv$. Then $ker(T_1)=[0, 0]$, $ker(T_2)=[0, 0]$ but $ker(T_1 + T_2)=[n, m]$ for $m,n \in R$

Are these examples correct? Can you give an example to (1) which is irrelevant to the chosen of basis?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by an example "which is irrelevant to the chosen of basis"

Comment: It's very easy to show that there are no counterexamples to (1). I  don't follow the argument you give for your (wrong) counterexample at all - you don't say anything about the images, you make comments on the kernels!

Comment: Sorry, a typo here. The question has been modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1)$ is true, so there is no counterexample:

If $y \in \operatorname{Im}(T_1 + T_2)$, there is $x$ with $y= (T_1 +T_2)x = T_1x + T_2x \in \operatorname{Im}T_1 +\operatorname{Im} T_2$, which shows that the claimed inclusion always holds.

$(2)$ Is false. Let $V$ be a non-zero vector space and consider your favorite injective linear map $T_1: V \to V$ (for example the identity map) and define $T_2:= -T_1$. Then

$$\ker(T_1 + T_2) = V$$
$$\ker T_1 \cap\ker T_2 = 0$$

so the inclusion can't hold.

Comment: How about $im(1+2)⊆im(1)+im(2)$? Is this always true?

Comment: My answer proves yes.

Comment: Sorry, a typo here. I mean is $(1)+(2)⊆(1+2)$ always true?

Comment: @user763288, just look at the example given for (2) and adapt it.

Comment: Take $T_1$ your favorite non-zero map and $T_2 = -T_1$. Then that inclusion can't be true.